# Show dynamic image (blob) by url in GAE(Python, Django)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am  trying to show image using template in Django:

template.html:

```
<img src='{{ url }}' alt="" />
```

{{ url }} define in views.py

views.py:

```
blob_key =str(product.key())
url = images.get_serving_url(blob_key)
```

product - simple object, define in models.py:

```
class Product(db.Model):
      name = db.StringProperty()
      price = db.FloatProperty()
      added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
      image = db.BlobProperty(default=None)
```

After all, I get `url = u'http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/ag5kZXZ-dmVydGlrYWwtM3INCxIHUHJvZHVjdBgEDA'`

In admin console item with `id = ag5kZXZ-dmVydGlrYWwtM3INCxIHUHJvZHVjdBgFDA`, **exist**.

But in brawser i don't see image.

Python 2.7

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What other method to display image in GAE, using Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using your Product instance's key as the basis for the URL, rather than the key to the `image` blob. Surely you mean:

```
url = images.get_serving_url(product.image)
```

Comment: try **blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(movie.image)** - result UnicodeDecodeError;

Comment: 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)'